# Does Java Crypto JCA Provider really require windows dll?

Tags: java, cryptography, certificate, smartcard

As I read here here:

> "Unlike most Java Cryptography Architecture (JCA) providers, the Sun
>   PKCS#11 Provider does not implement the cryptographic functionality
>   directly; it relies on a native PKCS#11 implementation to which it
>   forwards all operations. This implementation must be available as a
>   .dll file in Windows or a .so file in UNIX and Linux. For example, if
>   you use the Utimaco SafeGuard Smartcard Provider for Windows, the
>   PKCS#11 implementation is the library pkcs201n.dll."

Are smartcard provider obliged to have jca provider? For example where can I find jca provider for gemalto ?

Comment: You can get Gemalto stuff at Gemalto of course, don't ask us where to get licensed software. Gemalto probably also knows best if there is a JCA provider that works, it kinda depends on what the latest state of SW dev. at Gemalto is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [PKCS#11 Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html) is a good place to start.

Gemalto smart cards always ship with a PKCS#11 DLL, unfortunately it has different names depending on the card. Just look through the files that came with your installation until you find a DLL with "p" and "11" in it :)

After you located it, you may follow the steps given in the reference guide, i.e. create a configuration file that points to the PKCS#11 library etc. If everything went well, you should be able to access the smart card as simply as

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
ks.load(null, "pin".toCharArray());
```

Please note that for production code you should implement a proper `CallbackHandler` as outlined in the guide, of course - the above is just for a quick check that everything works.

Comment: hello thanks for answer. It's a pity that dll is required it means deployment to mass consumer is not easy since it will require some native installation procedure which is not easy if client machine is within a corporate environment.

Comment: Who are you telling? I faced that exact problem :) But without wanting to advertise companies or brands, search the Internet for PKCS#11 devices that do not need native PKCS#11 drivers. I found a solution that works without any installation at all on Windows. It simulates the PKCS#11 interface via USB commands. Pretty cool on the technical level and just marginally slower than "pure" PKCS#11. Impressed me, at least.

Comment: I searched but couldn't find can't you tell your secret ;)

Comment: @user310291 I would assume we're not allowed to advertise products here... but just send me a mail, I'll tell you there!

Answer (score 4):

> Are smartcard provider obliged to have jca provider? For example where
>   can I find jca provider for gemalto ?

No, of course not, that fully depends on what's in the contract. It's quite likely you get a PKCS#11 compatible library (with more or less functionality depending on the provider/card). It's likely but probably not fully tested that this is compatible with the PKCS#11 provider, which is a bit picky on how things are configured. The delivery of an actual JCA provider is a rarity, and you are lucky if you can get one that actually works.

[EDIT]

About the different question in the title: only the Sun PKCS#11 provider requires you to configure a `.dll`. Others may require one depending on the implementation. If the provider depends on OS support (e.g. the CAPI provider uses Windows functionality) it will probably require a non-configurable `.dll` or `.so` somewhere on the library path. Bouncy Castle and other pure Java providers generally don't require any `.dll` or `.so`.

Contact Gemalto to see if they have a JCA provider, they should know for sure.

Comment: Nitpick: The CAPI provider also requires native DLLs :)

Comment: @emboss: Yeah, that's the one that depends on OS support, thanks for replying with the name that kept circling my brain with ever larger circles :) I'll rewrite, the sentence was badly written in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

PKCS#11 DLL you are referring to is an interface between applications capable of using PKCS#11 API and the specific cryptographic hardware implementation. As each cryptographic hardware is different, it requires its own PKCS#11 DLL. Consequently, if the application is designed to communicate with cryptographic hardware via PKCS#11, it has to call the vendor-provided DLL. So it's not that Java doesn't have native implementation of PKCS#11, but just how PKCS#11 is designed to be used.

I don't think any hardware vendor is obliged to provide a JCA module and afaik many (if not most) of them only provide PKCS#11 drivers and CryptoAPI modules (CSP).